# Нужно создать слайдер ползунок на сайте asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Как на сайте asp.net mvs реализовать слайдер (ползунок) как [здесь](http://gnatkovsky.com.ua/krasivyj-polzunok-vybora-znacheniya-ui-polzunok-na-sajt.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте реализовать этот пример с JQuery  https://jqueryui.com/slider/ 
Да и вообще советую брать уже готовые решения для таких задач, а стили уже подгонять